# Can you help me figure out this SQL error

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I am receiving this error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fulltext =REPLACE(fulltext, 'http://als.affors.com', 'http://alsconsult.com' at line 1
>    `UPDATE josf_content SET introtext =REPLACE(introtext, 'http://als.affors.com', 'http://alsconsult.com') fulltext =REPLACE(fulltext, 'http://als.affors.com', 'http://alsconsult.com');`

I'm not sure what is wrong can you help me?

Comment: Please, next time look at the example and format your question until it looks better. Then, also paste the code you use. I can sort-of get the query from the error, but better would be if you'd have pasted it from your code, formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

The error says there's a problem before 'fulltext'. I suppose it is a missing `,`, so try something like

```
UPDATE josf_content SET 
introtext = 
REPLACE(introtext, 'http://als.affors.com', 'http://alsconsult.com')
,
fulltext = ....
```

(formatted it over several lines for clarity, but mind the `,` before the word fulltext)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you like this. If you tried something else, then why not post that in your question, with the error you got then? Also, add the code you are using. Unfortunatly I do not have a magic chrystal ball to find out what is going on. I was trying to actually let this question come to a happy end, but please, put in some effort tot the question. this is going no where like this.